# What is happening to my site in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

My site: [FIFA Encyclopedia](http://www.fifaencyclopedia.com)

A long time ago I made some big changes and incorporated a lot of PHP and used some Javascript to make the right and left sides automatically have the same height. It works perfect in Firefox and Chrome, but it just goes to hell in IE. I've been looking at it for awhile and I just can't figure it out. I'm thinking it has something to do with the Javascript I used, but I'm not sure exactly what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in deede its the javascript i got three errors from IE

```
  line 66 invalid argument" 
  myLeftColumn.style.height = (myRightHeight - myLeftExtras) + "px";

 line 149   myLeftColumn.style.height = (myRightHeight - myLeftExtras) + "px";

 line 323   myRightColumn.style.height = (myLeftHeight - myRightExtras) + "px";

 line  236 myRightColumn.style.height = (myLeftHeight - myRightExtras) + "px";
```

Comment: I've been looking at this and trying to fix it, but the lines aren't even where they should be. For example, line 66 has nothing to do with myLeftColumn ect. What did you do to show these errors? Do you have any idea what's wrong with my script? Thanks!

Comment: no sorry i didnt have time examine it, but it eather IE cant get the element id for `myLeftColumn`, i use ms script debugger